# Returning an array with the minimum and maximum elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
var numbers = [2,3,3,4,2,2,5,6,7,2];
```

I need to return an array with the signature `[minimum, maximum]`. I tried both a `for` loop and the following:

```js
var minValueNumber = Math.min.apply(null, numbers);
var minmax = (minValueNumber + " " + maxValueNumber);
```

However, this returned an error.

Comment: please edit the question title

Comment: what is the error? is it maxValueNumber is undefined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get min and max value and put them into an array.

By using [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), you need not to take [`Function#apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).

```js
var numbers = [2, 3, 3, 4, 2, 2, 5, 6, 7, 2],
    min = Math.min(...numbers),
    max = Math.max(...numbers),
    result = [min, max];

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `reduce` and in one iteration, you will get both min and max.

```js
var numbers = [2, 3, 3, 4, 2, 2, 5, 6, 7, 2];

const [min, max] = numbers.reduce(
  ([min, max], num) => [num < min ? num : min, num > max ? num : max],
  [Infinity, -Infinity]
);

console.log(min, max);
```